# How can I use the Python socket module to connect to the socket.io server in node.js?

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I created a server using socket.io in node.js. Then, using Python's socket module, we attempted to connect to the node.js server, which resulted in 400 errors. How can I solve this error? Here's my code.

app.js

```
var http = require('http').Server(app); //1
var io = require('socket.io')(http);    //1

var count=1;

io.on('connection', function(socket){ //3
  console.log('user connected: ', socket.id);  //3-1
  var name = "user" + count++;                 //3-1
  io.to(socket.id).emit('change name', name);   //3-1

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){ //3-2
    console.log('user disconnected: ', socket.id);
  });

  socket.on('send message', function(name,text){ //3-3
    var msg = name + ' : ' + text;
    console.log(msg);
    io.emit('receive message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(8000, function(){ //4
  console.log('server on!');
});
```

client.py

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

sio.connect('http://localhost:8000')
print('my sid is', sio.sid)

sio.emit('my message', {'foo': 'bar'})
```

Comment: Why not use the [Python socket.io client](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html)?

Comment: @ggorlen Can Python socket.io client solve this problem?

Comment: @ggorlen When I try to connect using Python socket.io Client, the following error occurs: ConnectionError OPEN packet not returned by server

Comment: You could try adding that code as well to the question. I'll take a look if I can. Can you connect using a standard JS browser client like shown in the docs?

Comment: @ggorlen I edited my questtion

Comment: @leedjango I had similar ConnectionError when using socket.io@2.4 Using version 3.1 doesn't work either. So far, I only had success with python-socketio=5.0.4 and socket.io@3.0.5